# hiding php created divs during onload with javascript

Tags: php, javascript, html, onload

I am running the javascript function shoh() below on page load to hide div's. This works fine on html hard coded divs but appears not to be working on divs that are created via php. Am I correct in assuming that the javascript runs first before the php creates the divs and that is why they aren't being hidden? If so, is there any other way to hide these divs after they are created? They need to be shown by default in case javascript is disabled?

code which runs with onload:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function closeAllDivs() {
  shoh('g1');
  shoh('g2');
  shoh('g3');
  shoh('g4');
    }   
</script>
<BODY onLoad="closeAllDivs();">
```

javascript to hide divs:

```
function shoh(id) { 

if (document.getElementById) { // DOM3 = IE5, NS6
    if (document.getElementById(id).style.display == "none"){
        document.getElementById(id).style.display = 'block';
        filter(("img"+id),'imgin');         
    } else {
        filter(("img"+id),'imgout');
        document.getElementById(id).style.display = 'none';         
    }   
} else { 
    if (document.layers) {  
        if (document.id.display == "none"){
            document.id.display = 'block';
            filter(("img"+id),'imgin');
        } else {
            filter(("img"+id),'imgout');    
            document.id.display = 'none';
        }
    } else {
        if (document.all.id.style.visibility == "none"){
            document.all.id.style.display = 'block';
        } else {
            filter(("img"+id),'imgout');
            document.all.id.style.display = 'none';
        }
    }
  }
}
```

php code which creates divs:

```
for ($i=0; $i < count($this->items); $i++){
  <div style="display: block;" id="g<? echo $i ?>">
  ... code that displays items
  </div>
}
```

Comment: $i is starting at 0, not 1. so the first call should be shoh('g0');

Comment: You should get rid of that `document.layers` and `document.all` stuff. Or do you really want to support ancient browsers like Netscape and IE5?

Comment: good catch with $i starting at 0 but fixing this does not change the problem. I've also fixed the post to "in case javascript is disabled." I am glad to hear I can get rid of document.layers and document.all - I am fairly new to using javascript and obvioiusly picked this code up from another source. Still, no one seems to have addressed the original issue...

Comment: The php block seems to be incomplete. There are some ?> and <?php missing in there to separate html and php.

Comment: Thanks  Tomás, you are correct. It is the problem with simplifying code for explanation purposes.

Answer (score 1):

It shouldn't really matter so much whether the php made the divs or whether they're hardcoded - by the time the HTML hits the browser, it's already the same thing.  The server processes the PHP - by the time it leaves the server and heads to the browser, there is no PHP anymore.

I'd recommend using `window.onload` instead of a `<body onload="">`

```
window.onload = function() {
    closeAllDivs();
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Wolfman Joe for letting me know the problem was likely not with the order of things. This told me the shoh() function was likely failing and therefore interrupting execution... so the code to close the divs was never executed. The solution was to build a check into the shoh() function to first make sure the div existed before attempting to change its property. As it turns out, not all divs $i were being created.

```
function shoh(id) { 
  if (document.getElementById) { // DOM3 = IE5, NS6
    if (document.getElementById(id)){
        if (document.getElementById(id).style.display == "none"){
            document.getElementById(id).style.display = 'block';
            filter(("img"+id),'imgin');         
        } else {
            filter(("img"+id),'imgout');
            document.getElementById(id).style.display = 'none';         
        }   
    }   
  }
}
```

Comment: If you're using Firefox, I'd recommend installing Firebug - it has a wonderful javascript console that will tell you exactly where javascript code is failing.  If you're using Chrome, the javascript console is an integral part of Chrome.  If you're using IE - go use one of those other two for debugging.  I'm unfamiliar with Safari or other browsers except for opening them up to make sure it works in them, too.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I actually have Firebug installed, but haven't realized what it can do. I will check it out.

Comment: Glad I could help.  The normal way, on Stack Overflow, to mark someone's comment or answer as useful is to up-rate it, by the way.